# Function destroying wrong object

Tags: collision-detection, game-maker

I am using the `collision_line_list` function to detect all objects of a type.

In this case, the object is **obj_CapMan**.

**Code:**

```
collision_line_list(obj_HatMan.x,obj_HatMan.y,mouse_x,mouse_y,obj_CapMan,false,true,listaCap,false);
```

This code is in an object that would be equivalent to the game administrator. What should not influence anything, but in any case, is the information.

**Full Code:**

```
listaCap=ds_list_create();
listaNum=collision_line_list(obj_HatMan.x,obj_HatMan.y,mouse_x,mouse_y,obj_CapMan,false,true,listaCap,false);

if(listaNum>0){
    instance_destroy(listaCap); 
    ds_list_destroy(listaCap);
}
```

As a result, none of the objects on the list are being destroyed, but another one that is neither the manager nor the **obj_CapMan**, is being destroyed.

**Documentation Link:**

https://manual-en.yoyogames.com/#t=GameMaker_Language%2FGML_Reference%2FMovement_And_Collisions%2FCollisions%2Fcollision_line_list.htm&rhsearch=collision_line&rhhlterm=collision_line_list%20collision_line

---

[image]

This red square is an object to detect a **headshot**.

**That same object that is being destroyed, even though it is not mentioned in that part of the code at any time:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your code:

> `instance_destroy(listaCap);`

You are destroying the instance referenced by `listaCap`, which is a data structure instead. GameMaker Studio doesn't have strong language types, and treats `listaCap` like a regular resource id; since you used it in the `instance_destroy()` function, GMS pretends it is an instance id and does its job. The result is, a random object is being destroyed.

You can fix your code by accessing the content of your `ds_list` and destroying the referenced instance:

```
if (listaNum > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listaNum; ++i) {
        instance_destroy(listaCap[| i]);
    }
    ds_list_destroy(listaCap);
}
```

Additionally, you may want to check if there's one instance only in your `ds_list` before destroying it, just to make sure no more issues arise.

Comment: At first I tried to do something like that. I put it inside a repeater and tried to destroy it using [| i]. But the program was not recognizing the list as a vector.

Comment: I will make the changes you indicated and I will return with the result.

Comment: You can also use [`ds_list_find_value()`](https://manual-en.yoyogames.com/#t=GameMaker_Language%2FGML_Reference%2FData_Structures%2FDS_Lists%2Fds_list_find_value.htm&rhsearch=ds_list) to read values alongside accessors.

Comment: What would the line look like: **instance_destroy(ListCap[| i]);** . If the list were a vector? **listaCap[i]**